# Distutils and shell expansion

Tags: python, bash, distutils

I have an extension module in Python that requires GTK.  Compiling a GTK program generally requires a TON of linkage, because GTK depends on so many other libraries (Glib, Cairo, Pango, etc.).  So, usually I just compile using the output of `pkg-config` by using shell expansion (back-ticks), like:

```
gcc -p-O2 -Wall myprogram.c -o myprogram `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --cflag `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

But for some reason, when I use shell expansion in an argument passed to `module.extra_compile_args` in distutils, I get an error because BASH doesn't actually expand the expression:

```
module = Extension('mymodule',
        sources = ['mymodule.c'])

module.extra_compile_args = ['`pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0`', 
        '`pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`'];
```

This just results in errors like:

```
gcc: error: `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0`: No such file or directory
```

So, is there any way to make this work?  Do I need to do the shell expansion manually by getting the output of `pkg-config` as a Python string and then adding it as an element in `module.extra_compile_args`?

Answer (score 2):

```
module.extra_compile_args = [
  subprocess.check_output(["pkg-config", "--cflags", "gtk+-3.0"]),
  subprocess.check_output(["pkg-config", "--libs", "gtk+-3.0"])
];
```

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output